# how to copy xml fiiles amazon from s3 to neptune

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-neptune

I am trying to move xml files from s3 to Neptune with bellow steps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-data.html

from the below path I have followed below topic to move the data from s3 to neptune
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-IAM.html

**•Creating an IAM Role to Allow Amazon Neptune to Access Amazon S3 resources**
I have created a role name "NeptuneLoadfroms3" as suggested in above topic

**•Adding the IAM Role to an Amazon Neptune Cluster**
I have followed the steps as suggested but in step5 mentioned that we need to add the role which created in previous topic , but I could not find the role name which was created Neputneloadfroms3.
It is showing role name is AWSServiceRoleForRDS

**•Creating the Amazon S3 VPC Endpoint**

Can some one help me to understand the role assignment  process .

My final goal is to copy xml file from s3 to Neptune.

Regards,
SP

Comment: Is there anything else you need with regards to this question?

Answer (score 0):

While creating the Role, did you attach the trust policy as mentioned in Step #13?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-IAM.html

Here is a sample trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "rds.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

By attaching this, you are basically allowing "rds.amazonaws.com" the ability to assume this role on your behalf. Only roles with this trust policy would appear in Neptune Console while attaching role to a cluster. Hope this helps.